# WP Pages: Add checkbox, save and display

Tags: posts

I am trying to add a check box for pages in editor, save and then print. The below code does add check box, however, it is not saving i.e. after clicking update button, the check box still remains unchecked.

```
function register_post_assets(){
add_meta_box('featured-page', __('Featured Page'), 'add_featured_meta_box', 'page', 'advanced', 'high');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'register_post_assets', 1);

function add_featured_meta_box($post){
$featured = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_featured-page', true);
echo "<label for='_featured-page'>".__('Feature this ppage')."</label>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='_featured-page' id='featured-product' value='1' ".checked(1, $featured)." />";
}

function save_featured_meta($post_id){
if(isset($_REQUEST['featured-page']))
    update_post_meta(esc_attr($post_id, '_featured-page', esc_attr($_REQUEST['featured-page'])); 
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_featured_meta');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using $_REQUEST['featured-page']? Your input name is _featured-page and you should use $_POST not $_REQUEST.

Try something like this.

```
add_action("admin_init", "register_post_assets");

function register_post_assets(){
    add_meta_box('featured-page', __('Featured Page'), 'add_featured_meta_box', 'page', 'advanced', 'high');
}

function add_featured_meta_box( $post ){
    global $post;

    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $_featured-page = $custom["_featured-page"][0];
    ?>

    <label>Featured Page</label>

    <?php

    $is_featured = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_featured-page', true);
    $checked = ($is_featured == "yes") ? 'checked="checked"' : null; ?>

    <input type="checkbox" name="_featured-page" value="yes" <?php echo $checked; ?> />
    <?php
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_featured_meta');
function save_featured_meta( $post_id ){
    global $post;

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    update_post_meta( $post_id, "_featured-page", $_POST["_featured-page"]);
}
```

Comment: I lost access to admin

unexpected =. because of $_featured-page = $custom["_featured-page"][0];

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: See codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom

Comment: error is unexpected = in line $_featured-page =